# What should be the sUrl and fUrl - PayU Money iOS integration

Tags: php, ios, swift, laravel, payumoney

I have successfully integrated PayU money mobile sdk. What I want is once transaction is completed I want to notify my server about the transaction state.

This can be done via `txnParam.surl`and `txnParam.furl`. when I set like this...

```
txnParam.surl = "http://staging.myserver.com/payu-success.php"
txnParam.furl = "http://staging.myserver.com/payu-fail.php"
```

I am getting Invalid sUrl in response from PayU money mobile sdk and not able to do the transaction.

But when I set like this...

```
txnParam.surl = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php"
txnParam.furl = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php"
```

I am able to do transaction and I am getting the success response from PayU money. **But how can I notify this to my server?**

**My Code**

```
    let txnParam = PUMTxnParam()
    PlugNPlay.setDisableCompletionScreen(true)

    txnParam.phone = "1111111111"
    txnParam.email = "test@test.com"
    txnParam.amount = "2550.0"
    txnParam.environment = PUMEnvironment.test
    txnParam.firstname = "test test"
    txnParam.key = kMerchentKey

    txnParam.merchantid = "5675943"
    txnParam.txnID = "1234567890"
//        txnParam.surl = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php"
//        txnParam.furl = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php"
    txnParam.surl = "http://staging.myserver.com/payu-success.php"
    txnParam.furl = "http://staging.myserver.com/payu-fail.php"

    txnParam.productInfo = "Test Product"
    txnParam.udf1 = "ud1"
    txnParam.udf2 = "ud2"
    txnParam.udf3 = "ud3"
    txnParam.udf4 = "ud4"
    txnParam.udf5 = "ud5"
    txnParam.udf6 = ""
    txnParam.udf7 = ""
    txnParam.udf8 = ""
    txnParam.udf9 = ""
    txnParam.udf10 = ""
```

Setting hash value got from server

```
txnParam.hashValue = serverHashValue
```

Presenting PlugNPlay view controller

```
PlugNPlay.presentPaymentViewController(withTxnParams: txnParam, on: self) { (response, error, extraParam) in
        print(response as Any)
        print(error as Any)
    }
```

**Backend: PHP(Laravel Framework)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of getting `sUrl is invalid` is **DASH(-)** in the url.

`http://staging.myserver.com/payu-success.php`.

Once I have set url like this...

`http://staging.myserver.com/payu_success.php`

It works gracefully.

But surprisingly `http://staging.myserver.com/payu-success.php` url (with dash) is working fine on ANDROID platform. :-O

But in iOS it was giving me wrong `sUrl`.

**This thing is not documented by PayU money**

So ultimately the funny thing is that after hours of trial and error finally get to know that

*DON'T USE DASH IN URL WHILE INTEGRATING PAYU MONEY IN IOS:D*

Hope it will help other

Comment: What about 'http://newbackend.hopto.org:5111/api/v1/Payment/callback?fareOrderToken=9cc2060b0c534ad7a7dae9d5938d900f' in ios. Its working fine in android, but not in ios.?